# UIView width is correct when not using .xib

Tags: ios, xcode

Has anyone else noticed in Xcode 6 different behaviour for loading a view controller with and without a .xib?

When there is an associated .xib, the view's width in `viewDidLoad` is always 320 (as it is set in Interface Builder). When loading without a .xib, the width is always accurate to the device proportions.

Is this intended behaviour?

Comment: @iAn I know where/when I can reliably get the view dimensions. I'm more curious about the difference in behaviour.

Comment: I'd like to be able to get the best of both, use a .xib and have the width set in time for viewDidLoad as well.

Comment: Can you stop posting drivel and actually listen to what I've asked.

Comment: I wouldn’t trust any sizes you see in `viewDidLoad`. You should wait for `viewWillAppear`/`viewDidAppear`. I suspect that any sizes or changes in sizes you see in `viewDidLoad` are due to implementation details.

Comment: It is an existing behaviour. in `viewDidLoad`, while loading from an XIB, you will always get whatever bounds you have set in XIB. the correct bounds can be obtained in `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear`.